# passing an object through a variable function

Tags: jquery

here is some relatively straightforward code I build about 2 years ago:

```
var armed=false;
function autosave(){
    if(armed){
        $('#console').html('submitting..');
        $('#autosave').val(1);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/gf5/console/resources/bais_01_exe.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            method: 'POST',
        }).done(function(data){
            //$('#cs').html('saved');
            $('#console').html('saved');
            armed=false;
        });
        $('#autosave').val('');
    }else{
        $('#console').html('idle'); 
    }
    setTimeout('autosave()',7000);
}
function arm(){
    armed=true;
    //$('#cs').html('active');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text],textarea').keyup(arm);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(arm);
    $('input[type=hidden]').change(arm);
    $('select').change(arm);
    setTimeout('autosave()',7000);
});
```

I want to now use this where only a specific field is submitted, not the entire form.#form1
Instead of:

```
$('textarea').keyup(arm);
```

How do I pass:

```
$('textarea').keyup(arm, this);
```

Where this = the object that the event came from?

Comment: Inside `arm` `this` *already* refers to the DOM element that triggered the event. In your example, `$('textarea').keyup(arm, this);`, `this` would refer to `window`. Have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: ^ What he said, and stop passing strings to setTimeout !